# JTextArea not being appended to in swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am currently working on a GUI calculator program using Swing. I got the actual interface done
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxTZx.png)

However, whenever I click on one of the number buttons, nothing appears in the operand text area, while 0.0 appears in the result text area as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDd5V.png).

Here is my code:

```
`
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static JTextArea operandArea;
    private static JTextArea resultArea;
    private static JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

    public Calculator()
    {
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setSize(800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        BorderLayout calculatorLayout = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(calculatorLayout);

        JPanel wholeCalculator = new JPanel();
        add(wholeCalculator);
        JPanel textAreas = new JPanel();
        wholeCalculator.add(textAreas, calculatorLayout.NORTH);
        textAreas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
        JPanel numberPad = new JPanel();
        wholeCalculator.add(numberPad, calculatorLayout.SOUTH);
        numberPad.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));

        operandArea = new JTextArea();
        operandArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,75));
        resultArea = new JTextArea();
        resultArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,75));

        textAreas.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        JLabel operand = new JLabel("Operand");
        JLabel result = new JLabel("Result");
        textAreas.add(operand);
        operand.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textAreas.add(operandArea);
        textAreas.add(result);
        result.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        textAreas.add(resultArea);

        numberPad.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        JPanel numbers = new JPanel();
        numberPad.add(numbers);
        numbers.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        numbers.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        JPanel operations = new JPanel();
        numberPad.add(operations);
        operations.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
        JButton minus = new JButton("-");
        minus.setActionCommand("minus");
        operations.add(minus);
        JButton plus = new JButton("+");
        plus.setActionCommand("plus");
        operations.add(plus);
        JButton multiply = new JButton("X");
        multiply.setActionCommand("multiply");
        operations.add(multiply);
        JButton divide = new JButton("/");
        divide.setActionCommand("divide");
        operations.add(divide);
        JButton decimal = new JButton(".");
        operations.add(decimal);
        JButton reset = new JButton("reset");
        reset.setActionCommand("reset");
        operations.add(reset);
        JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
        operations.add(clear);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            JButton temp = new JButton(i + " ");
            buttons[i] = temp;
            temp.addActionListener(this);
            numbers.add(temp);
        }
            numbers.add(new JButton("0"));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String action = e.getActionCommand();
        double initializer = 0.0;
        String operand = "";

        resultArea.setText(Double.toString(initializer));

        switch (action)
        {
            case "0":
                operandArea.append("0");
                operand = operand + "0";
                break;
            case "1":
                operandArea.append("1");
                operand = operand + "1";
                break;
            case "2":
                operandArea.append("2");
                operand = operand + "2";
                break;
            case "3":
                operandArea.append("3");
                operand = operand + "3";
                break;
            case "4":
                operandArea.append("4");
                operand = operand + "4";
                break;
            case "5":
                operandArea.append("5");
                operand = operand + "5";
                break;
            case "6":
                operandArea.append("6");
                operand = operand + "6";
                break;
            case "7":
                operandArea.append("7");
                operand = operand + "7";
                break;
            case "8":
                operandArea.append("8");
                operand = operand + "8";
                break;
            case "9":
                operandArea.append("9");
                operand = operand + "9";
                break;
            case ".":
                operandArea.append(".");
                operand = operand + ".";
                break;
            case "plus":
                initializer += Double.parseDouble(operand);
                resultArea.setText(Double.toString(initializer));
                break;
            case "minus":
                initializer -= Double.parseDouble(operand);
                resultArea.setText(Double.toString(initializer));
                break;
            case "multiply": initializer *= Double.parseDouble(operand);
                resultArea.setText(Double.toString(initializer));
                break;
            case "divide":
                try
                {
                    if (operand == "0")
                    {
                        throw new DivideByZeroException();
                    }
                    initializer /= Double.parseDouble(operand);
                    resultArea.setText(Double.toString(initializer));
                }
                catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
                {
                    resultArea.setText("Cannot divide by 0");
                }
                break;
            case "clear":
                operandArea.setText("");
                break;
            case "reset":
                operandArea.setText("");
                resultArea.setText("");
                initializer = 0.0;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator frame = new Calculator();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
`
```

I thought using the append command would add to the blank space? I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a compound one.

First, you create the button using...

```
JButton temp = new JButton(i + " ");
```

This, by default, sets the `actionCommmand` to `i_` <- not the space! (So won't let me put in a trailing space, so I've use `_` to highlight)

You then use

```
    switch (action)
    {
        case "0":
        //...
```

To check the `actionCommand`, but the command isn't (as an example) [`0`], it's [`0_`]

Instead, use something like...

```
JButton temp = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
```

You're also going to want to fix:

```
if (operand == "0")
```

as `==` is not how you should be comparing `Strings (and a good IDE should be warning you about it).  Instead use`equals`, for example...

```
if ("0".equals(operand))
```

Comment: I came to this same conclusion by dumping the value of his action command in a println statement with asterisks on either side. That's when I saw the space. He could also add `temp.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));` when creating the numeric buttons.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I do know that you should use the equals method when comparing strings, it's just that in the moment I forgot 0 was a string and I didn't pay much attention to the warning IntelliJ was giving. Now I have a new problem. None of the buttons on the right side of the calculator (ie +, -, reset, ., etc) are doing anything. Do I need to make another switch statement for those buttons?

Comment: @naasik Stack Overflow uses a question and answer format. You ask one question, you get one (accepted) answer. Click the checkmark to the left of this answer so MadProgrammer can get his interwebz points and post your new question separately. Once that's done, I (or someone else) will look for it and answer it. I guarantee if I can do this within 20 minutes or so, I'll be looking at it.

Comment: Sorry didn't know. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @naasik You've not registered any `ActionListener`s to those buttons